# Kendo Grid - Add Destroy (Delete) command in edit popup

Tags: kendo-grid

I need to add Destroy(Delete) command inside Edit Popup of Kendo Grid.
So edit popup will have 3 buttons, (1)Update (2)Cancel (3)Delete

Please provide me steps/details to achieve this if it is possible.

Thanks.